# Print functions for data projection and rename file

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, error-999999, error-000735

I have been struggling with functions in this script as I would like to see the projection in the file and then rename. The problem is that it causes and definitions are not done properly

Here is the long code:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --

# Exercise 1 - rename and redefine

# ===================================== Imports ======================================= #

# import all necessary libraries here
import arcpy
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil
from os import path
from arcpy.sa import *

# ===================================== Functions ======================================= #
# define your function(s) here

# finding the british grid projection
def british_grid_projection(in_shp):
  # input data is in NAD 1983 UTM Zone 11N coordinate system
  input_features = r"C:\Users\Leon\prog_gis_coursework\part_a_gis_functions\test_data\London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp"
  # output data
  output_feature_class = r"C:\Users\Leon\prog_gis_coursework\part_a_gis_functions\test_dataLondon_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp"
  # create a spatial reference object for the output coordinate system
  out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('')
  # run the tool
  arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_feature_class, out_coordinate_system)
  print ( "brit_grid_projection_processing")

def rename_files (brit_grid):
    # retrieve file names from the list
  file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Leon\prog_gis_coursework\part_a_gis_functions\test_data")
  print (file_list)

    # renaming the file

def main(duplicate):
    # make a duplicate of an existing file
  if path.exists("London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp"):
# get the path to the file in the current directory
    src = path.realpath("London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp");

# rename the original file
    os.rename("London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp","ldnboroughs_britgrid.shp")


# ====================================== Main script ====================================== #
# the execution starts here.
print ("Script starting")

# set up environment
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Leon\prog_gis_coursework\part_a_gis_functions\test_data"

# using the try tool

try:
    # set local variables
    in_dataset = "London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp"

    # get the coordinate system from the shapefile
    dsc = arcpy.Describe("London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp")
    coord_sys = dsc.spatialReference

    # run the tool
    arcpy.Project_management("London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp", "ldn_britgrid")

    # print messages when the tool runs successfully
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex.args[0])


# Calling all 3 functions here

british_grid_projection('in_shp')
rename_files('brit_grid')
main('duplicate')

print( "Script finished!")
```

Here is the error codes

```
Script starting
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Output Coordinate System: Value is required
Failed to execute (Project).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leons\Documents\part_a_gis_functions\folder for export\part a\Question 1 - new draft.py", line 84, in <module>
    british_grid_projection('in_shp')
  File "C:\Users\Leons\Documents\PGIS\part_a_gis_functions\folder for export\part a\Question 1 - new draft.py", line 29, in british_grid_projection
    out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 StatePlane Nevada West FIPS 2703 Feet')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 949, in __init__
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Comment: Please clarify what happens when using this script. Do you receive errors?

Comment: Script starting
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Output Coordinate System: Value is required
Failed to execute  line 31, in british_grid_projection
    arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_feature_class, out_coordinate_system)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 8825, in Project
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Project). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000614: Cannot create Spatial Reference for out_coor_system.

Comment: What is your desired output coordinate system? Right now it's just set as a blank in the british_grid_projection function.

Comment: NAD 1983 State Plane California

Comment: There are multiple state plane systems in California. Check sources such as spatialreference.org to find out which one you need, or you can take the definition from an existing shapefile or feature class.

Comment: Please include all extra information in the question post itself, and not just in comments (use the 'Edit' link below the question).

Comment: Taking a step back, I think we need clarification. The comments in the code about the British Grid system are confusing. Please edit your question to include your error message(s) and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I have attached the error codes within the file. I hope this helps

Comment: While testing I think you should remove your try\except statements because they can mask otherwise useful information.  Are you trying to run this code as a Python Script tool, from IDLE, from another IDE or using some other way?